# Spring boot micro meter datadog socket connection error

Tags: spring-boot, datadog, spring-micrometer

I am working on to create some custom metrics for my spring boot 2 rest api. I have added the required micro meter and datadog dependency. My office machine works behind a proxy. I have setup proxy through spring boot plugin.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxxx.proxy.com
-Dhttp.proxyPort=xxxx
```

below are in my application.properties file. 
    management.metrics.export.datadog.apiKey=mykey

```
management.metrics.export.datadog.uri=https://app.datadoghq.com

management.metrics.export.datadog.enabled=true

management.metrics.export.datadog.step=10s
```

But I am getting the socket connection timeout.

```
   [datadog-metrics-publisher] 10 Apr 2020 16:51:39,552 WARN  DatadogMeterRegistry [{}]: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
    at io.micrometer.core.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send(HttpUrlConnectionSender.java:96)
    at io.micrometer.core.ipc.http.HttpSender$Request$Builder.send(HttpSender.java:284)
    at io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry.publish(DatadogMeterRegistry.java:141)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry.publishSafely(PushMeterRegistry.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
```

As far as I debugged the io.micrometer.core.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send method is failing and I dont under how the micro meter data dog takes the proxy details.

The micrometer doc says

```
management.metrics.export.datadog.uri=https://app.datadoghq.com # URI to ship metrics to. If you need to publish metrics to an internal proxy en-route to Datadog, you can define the location of the proxy with this.
```

But I dont understand what it means? should I replace this url with my proxy url or is there any specific uri pattern with the proxy?  I am using spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: Facing the same issue and using the same spring boot version. I have tried increasing the timeout to `15s` and configuring `-Dhttps.proxyHost` as well, neither of the two helped. For me the service is running in AWS EC2.

Comment: I updated the logging level to trace and the issues seems to be intermittent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to connect to an HTTPS URL for Datadog (`https://app.datadoghq.com` in your example), then you will need to set the `https.proxyHost` system property for it to have effect - `http.proxyHost` is for HTTP URLs[1]. These are system-wide settings that will be used by the default `HttpSender` (`HttpUrlConnectionSender`) if a `Proxy` is not passed to its constructor.

> The micrometer doc says
>
> ```
> management.metrics.export.datadog.uri=https://app.datadoghq.com # URI to ship metrics to. If you need to publish metrics to an internal proxy en-route to Datadog, you can define the location of the proxy with this.
> ```
>
> But I dont understand what it means? should I replace this url with my
>   proxy url or is there any specific uri pattern with the proxy?

This is referring to a different kind of proxy that you would configure to receive your Datadog traffic on your internal network, and it would forward it to Datadog outside of your network. If you are using an HTTP proxy then you should use the system properties or an `HttpSender` with your HTTP proxy configured (e.g. an `HttpUrlConnectionSender` and passing a `Proxy` to its constructor).

You can configure a custom `HttpSender` with a `DatadogMeterRegistry` using its `Builder`. If you expose this as a `Bean` in a `@Configuration` class, Spring Boot will use it in its auto-configuration. For example:

```
@Bean
public DatadogMeterRegistry datadogMeterRegistry(DatadogConfig config, Clock clock) {
    HttpSender httpSender = new HttpUrlConnectionSender(config.connectTimeout(), config.readTimeout(), new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("myproxy", 8080)));
    return DatadogMeterRegistry.builder(config).clock(clock).httpClient(httpSender).build();
}
```

---

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Thanks. Tommy, we did set the https proxy details but we had no luck. We will try the spring bean option. Thanks for the help. I will come back and post my result here. Thanks